# Bash script Illegal number error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to code some program to detect a video freeze on a RaspberryPi and I'm having trouble on my bash script.
Here is what I've done to compare two screenshots in order to detect the freeze :

```
    #!bin/bash

    while true
    do
         sudo rm -rf /home/pi/shots/*
         sudo raspi2png -p /home/pi/shots/screen1.png -d 5
         sudo raspi2png -p /home/pi/shots/screen2.png -d 5
         ndiff=`compare -metric AE /home/pi/shots/screen1.png /home/pi/shots/screen1.png null:`
         if [ "$ndiff" -lt "100" ] ;
         then
                 sudo reboot
         fi
     done
```

I followed those intructions : [Compare 2 images and find % difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378134/compare-2-images-and-find-difference)
but I think the illegal number comes from ndiff, can you please tell me what can I do ?
Thanks

Comment: what does `echo "$ndiff"` produce?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I have a blank. But just after my commande line compare I have this : 17727+ ndiff =

Comment: Exact error : :10 : [: Illegal number:

Comment: you are missing a space after `"100"`

Comment: I put it in the real code, just wrote it wrong on the post, sorry

Comment: What is the exact value of ndiff after the compare command?

Comment: I told you above 17727 but it depends on the comparaison. But I do an echo, I see nothing below it, this is why I think ndiff doesn't take any value.

Comment: @KWa : I am not sure if `compare` is the right tool for you after reading the manual

Comment: @sjsam What do you suggest ?

Comment: Only 17727? then what is this : `17727+ ndiff = –`? and how did you get this?

Comment: @Jahid I get this when I run my program, juste after the compare line : I think it's the result of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff` instead of `compare` :

```
   dif=$(diff /home/pi/shots/screen1.png /home/pi/shots/screen1.png)    
#if the two files are exactly the same the $dif will be empty    
if [ -z "$dif" ] #checking if  $dif is empty or unset
then
   sudo reboot
fi
```

Or perhaps try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151593/1620779) method.

Comment: Sorry but I still have a problem with your code, when I run it it tells me that their is a Binary: not found error. I think your code doesn't work with .png's ..

Comment: @k.wa. I tried with pngs and it worked... Perhaps try the other solution pointed to by the link is more suitable. I tried that too

Comment: @K.Wa : What was your final solution?

Comment: sudo diff /home/pi/shots/screen1.png /home/pi/shots/screen2.png
         if [ $? -eq 0 ]
         then
                 sudo reboot
         fi
     done